# Error during "Make Install" while installing Player

Tags: compiling, make

I want to install Player on Ubuntu Platform.

1. I run `configure`. This is done successfully.
2. When running `sudo make install` afterwards, I get the following error:

   ```
   Making install in replace
   make[1]: Entering directory `/home/khimya/player-2.1.2/replace'
   if /bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -I../libplayercore -I../client_libs/libplayerc++ -I../client_libs/libplayerc     -g -O2 -MT poll.lo -MD -MP -MF ".deps/poll.Tpo" -c -o poll.lo poll.c; \
       then mv -f ".deps/poll.Tpo" ".deps/poll.Plo"; else rm -f ".deps/poll.Tpo"; exit 1; fi
    gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -I../libplayercore -I../client_libs/libplayerc++ -I../client_libs/libplayerc -g -O2 -MT poll.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/poll.Tpo -c poll.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/poll.o
   In file included from poll.c:26:
   replace.h:100: warning: ‘struct timespec’ declared inside parameter list
   replace.h:100: warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want
   In **file included from poll.c:34:
   **/usr/include/unistd.h:275: error: two or more data types in declaration specifiers**
   poll.c: In function ‘poll’:**
   poll.c:79: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘alloca’
   make[1]: *** [poll.lo] Error 1
   ```

Could anyone please tell what could be done precisely?

```
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/khimya/player-2.1.2/replace'
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Comment: please provide the output of your `./configure`

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem while installing a recent version of gnuplot (I also got an "error 2"). In fact I found your question looking up for an answer, and I solved it just by using 
`sudo make install`
instead of only 
`make install`
because I saw someone in another question writing it in that way...

I hope this works for you...